# How to enable the UISwitch in all of the custom cells in UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a `UITableView` which created with `custom cell`.
Every custom cell has a UISwitch in it like the stock Alarm Clock app in the iPhone.
I want to be enable each and every `UISwitch` in my `UITableView` cells.
Please help me ...

Comment: You want to enable it in ONLY ALL of them?

Comment: yes . i want to enable uiswitch in all cells. like Alarm Clock in iPhone .

Answer (score 0):

This code is not universal and you should refactor it, but that is the main idea.

```
- (void)enableOnlyAllTheSwitches{
    int objectsCount = [myObjectsDataStructure count];
    for (int i=0; i++; i<objectsCount){
        NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
        [cell.switch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank but my tableview id disble. I wanted each of them to get active .

Comment: similar Alarm Clock in iPhone .

Answer (score 0):

I found my Answer :

```
MyTableView.allowsSelection=NO;

MyTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing=YES;
```

This work very good ...